# Design change in the badge counts

Tags: support, design, badges, profile-page

In the last few days I noticed that, border color was applied for the badge counts in the Profile and Activity tabs. I thought of it is a new design change.

> [image: Profile page]

So I checked in the [Stack Overflow Design - Badge counts](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/badges#badge-counts) page, but there is no design change for the badge counts.

> [image: Design page]

Is the badge count design changed intentionally? If so, the SO Design site not updated correctly? Or it is a bug?

Comment: @Luuklag No. Notice is different than the badge count.

Comment: The answer is the same, although the subject is different.

Comment: Looks like the Stacks design page hasn't been updated yet.